# What's the term when you assign a new method to a term in Python?

Tags: python

I'm not sure if I worded that correctly! I think it's called reassignment but again i'm not sure. Here is an example of what i'm talking about:

```
line = line.replace(word, "")
```

would it be called line reassignment? I'm looking for the technical term.

Comment: variable reassignment.

Comment: "reassignment" is perfectly good word for that.

Comment: I doubt there is a technical term; there's nothing particularly special about reusing a name from the right-hand side of the assignment as the target. "Reassignment" is descriptive, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no 'technical' term as such and yes its called reassignment which makes an existing variable refer to a new value.